# IPA installation on friends iPhone 6+ via Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: iphone, xcode6

Can some one tell me what is the quickest way to install an app ipa or via cable on friends device, where no certificate or provisioning profiles are create for friends device. I would like to know correct and ethical answer. No jailbreak or anything.

Xcode 6.1.1 and friends phone iPhone 6+

Comment: You can't. And don't insist too much on "friends phone". It won't help making it look like legit.

Comment: Let me just clarify.. I have developer program. Its just that I want to install it on device which does not belong to me. Hence I am not interested in creating provising profiles for someone else phone.

If legally there is no other way... I will create a provising profile.

Comment: Okay, this is a good clarification. No, you can't do that unfortunately.